# How to group logging messages in log4net by namespace?

Tags: c#, log4net, ioc-container

I'm trying to implement own log4net appender, that would group messages by namespace into groups.
Problem is, that i can't get log4net to log LocationInformation, as i would like.

```
  class Program
{
    protected static IWindsorContainer container;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));

        // add facilities
        container.AddFacility("logging.facility", new LoggingFacility(LoggerImplementation.Log4net, "log4net.config"));
        container.Register(Component.For<ParentClass>().ImplementedBy<ParentClass>());
        container.Register(Component.For<ChildClass>().ImplementedBy<ChildClass>());                      

        var parentClass = container.Resolve<ParentClass>();
        var childClass = container.Resolve<ChildClass>();
        parentClass.Init();
        childClass.Init();

    }
}

public class ParentClass
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    private ILog localLogger;

    public ParentClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        localLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
        logger.Info("ctor ioc logger, type: {0}",GetType().Name);
        localLogger.Info(string.Format("ctor local logger, type: {0}", GetType().Name));
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        logger.Info("init ioc logger, type: {0}", GetType().Name);
        localLogger.Info(string.Format("init local logger, type: {0}", GetType().Name));
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
    {

    }
}
```

output is

```
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - ctor ioc logger, type: ParentClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - ctor local logger, type: ParentClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - ctor ioc logger, type: ChildClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - ctor local logger, type: ChildClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - init ioc logger, type: ParentClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - init local logger, type: ParentClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - init ioc logger, type: ChildClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - init local logger, type: ChildClass
```

problem is, that log4net class name always outputs as base class name (ParentClass). I've thought initially, that may be castle windsor, that is causing such problem, but as results show, even if i create logger instance manually, it still logs base class name. May be anyone has idea, how to force log4net write actual instance class name?

**update**

here goes log4net config used:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="c:\temp\testlog.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %level %thread %C{1} - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />      
</root>
```

output above is what i get, what i expect to get is:

```
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - ctor ioc logger, type: ParentClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - ctor local logger, type: ParentClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ChildClass - ctor ioc logger, type: ChildClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ChildClass - ctor local logger, type: ChildClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - init ioc logger, type: ParentClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ParentClass - init local logger, type: ParentClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ChildClass - init ioc logger, type: ChildClass
2011-03-28 09:58:55 INFO 10 ChildClass - init local logger, type: ChildClass
```

**update 2**

in case anybody needs such thing, here is working appender implementation:

```
public class GroupStringListAppender : log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton
{
    private readonly int listLength = 30;
    private readonly Func<string, string> pathFuction;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> messagesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public GroupStringListAppender(int listLength, Func<string, string> pathFuction)
    {
        this.listLength = listLength;
        this.pathFuction = pathFuction;
    }

    public List<string> GetMessages(string path)
    {
        return messagesDictionary[path];
    }        

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        var msg = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage;
        var path = pathFuction.Invoke(loggingEvent.LoggerName);

        if (!messagesDictionary.ContainsKey(path))
        {
            messagesDictionary.Add(path, new List<string>());
            OnNewPathCreated(path);
        }

        var list = messagesDictionary[path];        

        while (list.Count - listLength > 0)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(0);    
        }

        list.Add(msg);

        OnAppended(path, list);          
    }

    public event AppendedEventHandler Appended;

    public void OnAppended(string path, List<string> list)
    {
        AppendedEventHandler handler = Appended;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new LoggerMessageAppendedEventArgs(path, list));
    }

    public event NewPathCreatedHandler NewPathCreated;

    public void OnNewPathCreated(string path)
    {
        var handler = NewPathCreated;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new NewPathCreatedHandlerArgs(path));
    }
}

public delegate void NewPathCreatedHandler(object sender, NewPathCreatedHandlerArgs args);

public class NewPathCreatedHandlerArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public NewPathCreatedHandlerArgs(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }
}

public class LoggerMessageAppendedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public List<string> List { get; set; }

    public LoggerMessageAppendedEventArgs(string path, List<string> list)
    {
        Path = path;
        List = list;
    }
}

public delegate void AppendedEventHandler(object sender, LoggerMessageAppendedEventArgs e);
```

Comment: Can we see your log4net.config ?

Comment: Is that the output you wanted, or the output you got? It seems from what you say that it's the output you wanted, but I'm wondering about the output you got (particularly in terms of init, which I'm expecting on reading this to be the same as that you say you wanted) before I weigh in with a suggestion that may not even match the behaviour found.

Comment: i've updated my question according to your comments, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `%logger` instead of `%C{1}` you will get the desired result at least for the local logger.

I think for IoC you need to do a little more. Have to investigate more on this...

Comment: from what I have read in the internet I guess that your IoC container already does everything correclty

Comment: right, problem was that i was using loggingEvent.LocationInformation.ClassName instead of loggingEvent.LoggerName in my appender (or as you mentioned, %C{1} instead of %logger in sample's configuration).